# Fetching data from Firestore works from ContentPage but not from class

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms for a mobile app, and using Firebase as a backend, I created a BaseRepository class with the following code:

```
public Task<IList<T>> GetAll()
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<T>>();
            var list = new List<T>();

            FirebaseFirestore.Instance
                .Collection(DocumentPath)
                .Get()
                .AddOnCompleteListener(new OnCollectionCompleteListener<T>(tcs));

            return tcs.Task;
        }
```

And a class UniversityRepository that inherits from the BaseRepository to set the "DocumentPath" property.

I created a test ContentPage with a simple test button to verify that the data is being pulled from Firestore:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var universities = await repository.GetAll();
            foreach (var u in universities)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(u.Name);
            }
        }
```

And it successfully prints the data.

Now I created a UniversityDataService class that will be responsible of populating the viewmodel data using the following method:

```
private async static Task<T> PopulateData<T>()
        {

            var repository = DependencyService.Get<IRepository<University>>();

            var universities = await repository.GetAll();
            var doc = new Dictionary<string, IList<University>> { { "universityPageList", universities } };

            T data;

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc))))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                data = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }


            return data;
        }
```

But for some inexplicable reason, it hangs at line:

```
var universities = await repository.GetAll();
```

At first I was getting the following message in the debug window:

> Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates
> that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the
> moment.

But then after a while I was not getting anything Firebase/Firestore related, the last messages printed on my debug windows is:

```
[nativeloader] classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86_64:/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86_64:/product/lib64:/system/product/lib64
[ProviderInstaller] Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
[NativeCrypto] Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
[m.App.app] Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
[m.App.app] Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
[m.App.app] WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ClassLinker for 9.315ms
[ProviderInstaller] Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
[m.App.app] Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
[m.App.app] Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
[m.App.app] Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
[m.App.app] Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, JNI, allowed)
[m.App.app] Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
[m.App.app] Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
[m.App.app] Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

And then it just crashes after a while with no exceptions/error messages on my VS window.

I can't think of any reason why is this happening, especially that the UniversityDataService is a custom class, not some special Android class that could be blocking network calls.

Whenever I debug and it fails, I directly check that the emulator is connected to the network, and yes it is.

Update:
Here is how the method is being called to populate the viewmodel:

1- The UniversityPage view binds to the viewmodel through the data service like the following:

```
public UniversityPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = UniversityDataService.Instance.UniversityPageViewModel;
    }
```

2- The UniversityDataService has a property that returns a the ViewModel after calling the PopulateData method like the following:

```
public class UniversityDataService
    {
         public UniversityPageViewModel UniversityPageViewModel =>
        this.universityViewModel ??
        (this.universityViewModel = PopulateData<UniversityPageViewModel>().Result);
    }
```

Update 2:

Attempt 1 based on Jason's comment:

I added the following to the view:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            this.BindingContext = new UniversityPageViewModel();
        }
```

And then changed the UniversityPageList property of the viewmodel to the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<University> UniversityPageList
        {
            get
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<University>(UniversityDataService.PopulateData());
            }
            set { }
        }
```

Then changed the PopulateData method in the data service to the following:

```
public static IList<University> PopulateDataVM()
        {

            var repository = DependencyService.Get<IRepository<University>>();

            var universities = repository.GetAll();
            //var doc = new Dictionary<string, IList<University>> { { "songsPageList", universities } };



            return universities.Result;
        }
```

Comment: have you tried calling it with MainThread?  I wouldn't expect that to make a difference, but it would be an easy thing to quickly check

Comment: @Jason Interesting, calling the PopulateData method that resides in the UniversityDataService from the test button does indeed gets the data from Firestore, I'm starting to think this has something to do with calling from view constructor?

Comment: how are you calling an aysnc method from the constructor?  You didn't post that code

Comment: I updated the post and added that part.

Comment: That seems extremely weird to me.  The VM should call the Service, the Service shouldn't be responsible for instantiating the VM.  And assign the VM in `OnAppearing` so you can use await

Comment: I agree with you on the bizarre structure, it was generated using Syncfusion framework and I decided to keep following it during the whole project, I guess I should've mention the use of Syncfusion even though it's not relevant in this case, I guess.
I updated the post with the new code following your instructions, no good so far.

Comment: Although, now I'm getting the Firestore error again:
[Firestore] (23.0.3) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
[Firestore] 
[Firestore] This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: your `Get` calls `                return new ObservableCollection<University>(UniversityDataService.PopulateData());` **every time**.  This is not good.  And you are using `Result` instead of `async/await`, also not good

Comment: I'm aware of it, I'm just trying to get it to work first, then I will work on improving the code, I don't think using Result instead of async/await would be the cause of the Firestore message I shared in the previous comment.

Comment: Does it still work at least once, but then give the message on a later attempt? If so, then  perhaps `DependencyService.Get<IRepository<University>>()` holds on to some resource. Is there `Dispose` or similar on `var repository`?

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear to me why it would hang, but per Jason's comments, lets do proper `async`. I'll show a "cautious" answer: Below code does the work on a background thread, then switches to MainThread to affect UI.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<University> UniversityPageList
{
    get => _universityPageList;
    }
    set {
        _universityPageList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<University> _universityPageList = new ObservableCollection<University>();

public void FillUniversities()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var universities = await UniversityDataService.PopulateData();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            UniversityPageList = new ObservableCollection<University>(universities);
        }
    }
}

public async Task<List<University>> PopulateData()
{
    ...
}
```

Note that I DON'T attempt to fill the universities at the same time as the page is loaded.

Instead, before or after displaying the page, call `FillUniversities`. If the page is displayed before the universities are received, an empty list will be there. Then when there is a response from DB, that list gets set to the received universities.

---

Slightly different code can be used to get the list, then display the page. For example:

```cs
var page = new UniversityPage();
var vm = (UniversityViewModel)UniversityPage.BindingContext;
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var universities = await UniversityDataService.PopulateData();
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        vm.UniversityPageList = new ObservableCollection<University>(universities);
        // Or GoToAsync .. whatever you use to show a page.
        MainPage = page;
    }
}
```